# Page Manager on a variant of the node url

Tags: 7, panels, chaos-tool-suite

I have overriden the default `/node/%node` layout using panels and the page manager, now I need to add some different content when the URL is `/node/%node/step2`.

I have added a variant, and on the selection rules I added the URL path on `/node/*/step2`. I also tried different URL paths like `/node/%node/step2` or even `*/step2`.

But if I go to that URL it doesn't show up, and returns me a 404. This seems odd since that, if no other variant would be found (like my new `/node/%node/step2`), the default `/node/%node` page should be shown instead of a 404.

So my question is: why am I receiving a 404 instead of my "step2" variant, or even the default node page?

I'm using Page Manager 7.x-1.12.

Comment: do you have any content at that address?

Comment: No, I need this to be a new page but based on the node content

Comment: it sounds like you're telling panels that there is a menu entry (content) at that address, and that panels should take over for the output, so when you try to navigate to the address it fails because there's no content

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only way to do it but I just add custom pages at `/admin/structure/pages` like:

```
/node/%node/admin
```

I guess there are some benefits to doing it separately instead of as a variant of the main `/node/%node` because now your selection rules etc. are easy to manage for different content types, for example.

Your arguments page should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is indeed how I solved it for now. I'm still looking for a way to add variants to existing pages like for example the node_edit page with path `/node/%node/edit`. The same happens there: when I add a variant with path `node/*/edit/step2` it results in a 404.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you create a new page for /node/%node/edit/step2 ?

Comment: It does. However, what would I do when I want a step3? Create a new page altogether? Or either create a page for `node/%node/edit/steps` with a variant `node/%node/edit/steps/step2`, step3, ...